# Resizing a Contact Details webpart image

Tags: css, image

We have a custom library for all of our user's profile pictures. They have recently been updated to High res photos. Now, within the Contact Details webpart, they are displaying their original size where they used to be 76 x 96 px

What is the best way to target this element so that I can reduce the size of the photos globally? There is no static ID on the img itself or any parents

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl44_g_5fb3cdfb_0813_49ca_b428_03242f69af8a_contactFieldCtrl"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS on the page like this:

```
img[class$="contactFieldCtrl"] {width:76px; height:96px;}
```

That should resize any  that ends with the text "contactFieldCtrl" to the proper size.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp